# PHP image generating error / cannot be displayed because it contain errors

Tags: php, image

I've been working on some sort of a hit counter with statistics PHP script and i ran into the following error: The image `http://localhost/site/counter.php` cannot be displayed because it contains errors.

Here is the piece of code that does the Image Generating:

```
// Generate Image

// Get Value from DB
if ($show == "last24h")
{

// Last24h
$islast = $time-24*60*60;
$totalips = mysql_query("SELECT count(id) FROM counter_ips WHERE time>='$islast'");
$value = mysql_result($totalips,0,0);
$title = "Last 24 hours";
mysql_free_result($totalips);
}
else
{

// Total Visitors   
$totalvisitors = mysql_query("SELECT sum(user) FROM counter_day");
$value = mysql_result($totalvisitors,0,0);
$title = "Total Visitors";
mysql_free_result($totalvisitors);  
}

// Short Value
if ( $value > 999 ) { $value = $value / 1000; $unit = "k"; }
if ( $value > 999 ) { $value = $value / 1000; $unit = "m"; }
if ( $value > 999 ) { $value = ">999"; $unit = "m"; }
else { 
if ( $value >=10 ) $value = round($value,0);
else $value = round($value,1);}
$value .= $unit;


// Variables
$title_font="OpenSans-Regular.ttf";
$value_font="OpenSans-Bold.ttf";

if ($size == "small")
{
$width = 90;
$height = 20;
$title_font_size = 8;
$value_font_size = 9;
$title_pos_y = 15;
$value_pos_y = 16;  

// short title
if ($show == "last24h") {$title="Last24h";}
else {$title="Visitors";}

// left title
$size = imagettfbbox($title_font_size, 0, $title_font, $title);
$titleWidth = $size[2] - $size[0];
$title_pos_x = 8;

// right center value
$size = imagettfbbox($value_font_size, 0, $value_font, $value);
$valueWidth = $size[2] - $size[0];
$space_left = $title_pos_x + $titleWidth;
$value_pos_x = $space_left + ((($width - $space_left) / 2) - ($valueWidth / 2));
}
else
{
$width = 90;
$height = 55;
$title_font_size = 8;
$value_font_size = 24;
$title_pos_y = 15;
$value_pos_y = 48;
// center title
$size = imagettfbbox($title_font_size, 0, $title_font, $title);
$textWidth = $size[2] - $size[0];
$title_pos_x = ($width / 2) - ($textWidth / 2);
// center value
$size = imagettfbbox($value_font_size, 0, $value_font, $value);
$textWidth = $size[2] - $size[0];
$value_pos_x = ($width / 2) - ($textWidth / 2);
}

//  Create a blank image
$im = imagecreatetruecolor($width,$height); 

// Colors
if ($style == "light")
{
$bg_color = imagecolorallocatealpha($im, 235,235,235,0);
$title_color = imagecolorallocate($im, 50,50,50);
$value_color = imagecolorallocate($im, 25,25,25);   
}
else
{
$bg_color = imagecolorallocatealpha($im, 50,50,50,0);
$title_color = imagecolorallocate($im, 255,255,255);
$value_color = imagecolorallocate($im, 255,255,255);
}
$shadow_color = imagecolorallocatealpha($im, 0,0,0,115);
$red = imagecolorallocate($im, 223,1,1);

// Fill BG color
imagefill($im, 0, 0, $bg_color);
// Red line
imageline($im,0,0,$width,0,$red);
imageline($im,0,1,$width,1,$red);
//  title
imagettftext ($im, $title_font_size, 0, $title_pos_x+2, $title_pos_y+2, $shadow_color, $title_font, $title); 
imagettftext ($im, $title_font_size, 0, $title_pos_x, $title_pos_y, $title_color, $title_font, $title); 
// value
imagettftext ($im, $value_font_size, 0, $value_pos_x+2, $value_pos_y+2, $shadow_color, $value_font, $value);
imagettftext ($im, $value_font_size, 0, $value_pos_x, $value_pos_y, $value_color, $value_font, $value); 

// image output
header ("Content-type: image/png");

// create PNG
imagepng($im);

// destroy temp image
imagedestroy($im);
```

I know that the whole header(); should always come 1st, but i have no idea where to move to it.

[EDITED]
Full Code:

```
            // Date and Time
            $time = time();
            $day = date("Y.m.d",$time); // YYYY.MM.DD
            $month = date("Y.m",$time); // YYYY.MM

            // Language
            $language = substr($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'],0,2);

            // IP address
            $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; 

            // Get Referrer and Page
            if (isset($_GET["ref"])) 
                {
                // from javascript
                $referer = $_GET["ref"];
                $page = parse_url($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], PHP_URL_PATH);  
                } 
            else 
                {
                // from php
                $referer = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
                $page = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; // with include via php       
                }   

            // Cleanup
            if (basename($page) == basename(__FILE__)) $page="" ; // count not counter.php

            $server_host = $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]; // Server Host
            if (substr($server_host,0,4) == "www.") $server_host = substr($server_host,4); // Server Host without www.

            $referer_host = parse_url($referer, PHP_URL_HOST); // Referrer Host
            if (substr($referer_host,0,4) == "www.") $referer_host = substr($referer_host,4); // Referer Host without www.

            // Adjust Search Engines
            // Google 
            if (strstr($referer_host, "google."))
                {
                $referer_query = parse_url($referer, PHP_URL_QUERY);
                $referer_query .= "&";
                preg_match('/q=(.*)&/UiS', $referer_query, $keys);

                $keyword = urldecode($keys[1]); // These are the search terms
                $referer_host = "Google"; // adjust host
                }

            // Yahoo    
            if (strstr($referer_host, "yahoo."))
                {
                $referer_query = parse_url($referer, PHP_URL_QUERY);
                $referer_query .= "&";
                preg_match('/p=(.*)&/UiS', $referer_query, $keys);

                $keyword = urldecode($keys[1]); // These are the search terms
                $referer_host = "Yahoo"; // adjust host
                }

            // Bing
            if (strstr($referer_host, "bing."))
                {
                $referer_query = parse_url($referer, PHP_URL_QUERY);
                $referer_query .= "&";
                preg_match('/q=(.*)&/UiS', $referer_query, $keys);

                $keyword = urldecode($keys[1]); // These are the search terms
                $referer_host = "Bing"; // adjust host
                }


            // Delete Old IPs
            $timecheck = mktime(0, 0, 0, date("n"), date("j"), date("Y")) - 48*60*60 ; // 48*60*60 => after 48 hours

            $delete = mysql_query("DELETE FROM counter_ips WHERE time < '$timecheck'");
            if (!$delete) 
            {
            die("Database Selection Failed: ".mysql_error());
            }

            // Delete Old Page, Eeferrer, Language and Keywords
            $old_day = date("Y.m.d", mktime(0, 0, 0, date("n"), date("j")-$oldentries, date("Y")) ); 

            $delete = mysql_query("DELETE FROM counter_page WHERE day<='$old_day'");
            $delete = mysql_query("DELETE FROM counter_referer WHERE day<='$old_day'");
            $delete = mysql_query("DELETE FROM counter_keyword WHERE day<='$old_day'");
            $delete = mysql_query("DELETE FROM counter_language WHERE day<='$old_day'");
            if (!$delete) 
            {
            die("Database Selection Failed: ".mysql_error());
            }

            // Insert a New Day
            $newday = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM counter_day WHERE day='$day'");
            if (!$newday) 
            {
            die("Database Selection Failed: ".mysql_error());
            }

            if (mysql_num_rows($newday)==0)
                { 
                mysql_query("INSERT INTO counter_day (day, user, view) VALUES ('$day', '0', '0')");
                }

            // Check Reload and Set Online Time
            $newuser = 0;
            $oldreload = $time-$reload;
            $userid = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM counter_ips WHERE ip='$ip' AND time>'$oldreload' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1");
            if (!$userid)
            {
            die("Database Selection Failed: ".mysql_error());
            }

            if (mysql_num_rows($userid)==0)
                {
                // New Visitor
                $newuser = 1;
                mysql_query("INSERT INTO counter_ips (ip, time, online) VALUES ('$ip', '$time', '$time')");
                mysql_query("UPDATE counter_day SET user=user+1, view=view+1 WHERE day='$day'");
                }
            else
                {
                // Reload Visitor
                $olduser = mysql_result($userid,0,0);
                mysql_query("UPDATE counter_ips SET online='$time' WHERE id='$olduser'");
                mysql_query("UPDATE counter_day SET view=view+1 WHERE day='$day'");
                }

            // Page
            if($page <> "") {

            $result = mysql_query("SELECT id from counter_page WHERE page='$page' AND day='$day'");
            if (!$result)
            {
            die("Database Selection Failed: ".mysql_error());
            }

                if (mysql_num_rows($result)==0)
                    {
                    mysql_query("INSERT INTO counter_page (day, page, view) VALUES ('$day', '$page', '1')");
                    }
                else
                    { 
                    $pageid = mysql_result($result,0,0);
                    mysql_query("UPDATE counter_page SET view=view+1 WHERE id='$pageid'");
                    }

            }
            // Referer
            if(stristr($server_host, $referer_host) === FALSE AND $referer_host<>"" AND $newuser == 1) {

            $result = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM counter_referer WHERE referer='$referer_host' AND day='$day'");
            if (!$result)
            {
            die("Database Selection Failed: ".mysql_error());
            }

                if (mysql_num_rows($result)==0)
                    {
                    mysql_query("INSER INTO counter_referer (day, referer, view) VALUES ('$day', '$referer_host', '1')");
                    }
                else
                    { 
                    $refererid = mysql_result($result,0,0);
                    mysql_query("UPDATE counter_referer SET view=view+1 WHERE id='$refererid'");
                    }

            }

            // Keywords 
            if(isset($keyword) AND $newuser == 1) {

            $result = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM counter_keyword WHERE keyword='$keyword' AND day='$day'");
            if (!$result)
            {
            die("Database Selection Failed: ".mysql_error());
            }

                if (mysql_num_rows($result)==0)
                    {
                    mysql_query("INSERT INTO counter_keyword (day, keyword, view) VALUES ('$day', '$keyword', '1')");
                    }
                else
                    { 
                    $keywordid = mysql_result($result,0,0);
                    mysql_query("UPDATE counter_keyword SET view=view+1 WHERE id='$keywordid'");
                    }

            }

            // Language 
            if($language<>"" AND $newuser == 1) {

            $result = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM counter_language WHERE language='$language'");
            if (!$result)
            {
            die("Database Selection Failed: ".mysql_error());
            }   

                if (mysql_num_rows($result)==0)
                    {
                    mysql_query("INSERT INTO counter_language (day, language, view) VALUS ('$day', '$language', '1')");
                    }
                else
                    { 
                    $languageid = mysql_result($result,0,0);
                    mysql_query("UPDATE counter_language SET view=view+1 WHERE id='$languageid'");
                    }
                }
```

And the 2 errors now are the following:

- Notice: Undefined index: HTTP_REFERER in C:\wamp\www\site\counter.php on line 27
- Notice: Undefined variable: unit in C:\wamp\www\site\counter.php on line 245

and this is the code am using on my pages to do the counting:

```
<a href="<?php echo $siteurl; ?>admin/login.php">Admin Login</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
document.write('<a href="stats.php"><img src="counter.php?ref=' + escape(document.referrer) + '" border="0"></a>')
</script>
<noscript><a href="stats.php"><img src="counter.php" border="0"></a></noscript>
```

Comment: The header doesn't have to come first, just before _any_ output.

Comment: Are you getting any error messages when you remove the Content-Type header? If you remove this, then regular PHP warnings, notices and errors will appear. If none are appearing, try putting error_reporting(E_ALL) at the top to display these errors. Let us know what you see.

Comment: When I run it at http://william.isted.me/lab/ting.php minus the fonts (I don't have them) it seems to output an image

Comment: Okay, i managed to get the 2 errors that might be causing this issue. I added the rest of the script to my main post and the 2 additional errors. Hope you guys can find out what have i done wrong. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing:

```
        // Get Referrer and Page
        if (isset($_GET["ref"])) 
            {
            // from javascript
            $referer = $_GET["ref"];
            $page = parse_url($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], PHP_URL_PATH);  
            } 
        else 
            {
            // from php
            $referer = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
            $page = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; // with include via php       
            }
```

to:

```
        // Get Referrer and Page
        if (isset($_GET["ref"])) 
            {
            // from javascript
            $referer = $_GET["ref"];
            $page = ((isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])) ? (parse_url($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], PHP_URL_PATH)) : (''));  
            } 
        else 
            {
            // from php
            $referer = ((isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])) ? ($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) : (''));
            $page = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; // with include via php       
            }
```

and as for the other error I am not sure because that line of code seems to be missing from your post.

Comment: Oh sorry, the 2nd error is in the Generating Image section. // Short Value